Decomposition of a quantum gate into Rx Ry Rz
Can we break any quantum 2 qubit gate as a product of Rx Ry and Rz gates if yes then please provide a python code to do so .

No, it is not. You need a two-qubit gate like CNOT or CZ. The gates you mentioned are only single-qubit one. This prevents you from preparing entangled qubits which is crucial for QC.

to the down/close-voters - what is unclear about this question?

@forky40 the questioner did not provide any effort to explain what they did or where they are stuck. It's not appropriate for us to have to guess this.  Further the questioner's tone seems demanding of volunteer's time.

As mentioned in the comments, it's not possible. For instance, if you were able to implement the controlled-$X$ gate using only single-qubit rotations, then you could create the entangled state:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle+|11\rangle\right)$$
by starting from the $|00\rangle$ state, applying an $H$ gate on the first qubit and then the controlled-$X$ gate on the second.
But applying single-qubit rotations on $|00\rangle$ can only result in a separable state, hence the contradiction.
